# PgAdmin 4: Terminate database backup process

Tags: pgadmin-4, pg-dump

I am attempting to back up a PostgreSQL database from pgAdmin 4, but a pg_dump backup process is already running, and I am unable to stop it.

I've restarted the postgres server, restarted the server OS, and restarted pgAdmin, but the pg_dump backup process is still running.

Update: Removing and reinstalling postgresql and pgAdmin 4 did not solve the problem. The backup process resumed.

How can I stop this process?

Comment: I had to kill the process with task manager. Because of this (and many other) problem I decided to wait until the developers finish up their work on PgAdmin4 and have installed [old good PgAdmin3](https://bigsql.org/postgresql/installers.jsp), still [supported by BIGSQL](https://bigsql.org/pgadmin3/index.jsp).

Comment: Same here, absolute nightmare. Even when we restart pgAdmin 4, the backup is still on going. Even after killing the process. I had to stop the pg server, kill the process several times to make it stop

Answer (score 0):

I managed to stop it (actually fail it and then close it) by doing this workaround:

- closing PGAdmin 4
- killing all pg_restore/pg_admin processes
- for restore: rename/move/delete file restoring from
- for backup: temporarily remove access rights from target filesystem (or rename target folder to "break the path" in the PGAdmin job)

Next time you open PG-Admin it will try to start the job again, but will fail immediately. Open details and close with "X" and it's gone.

Comment: @ChetanPurohit possibly you have a different version. what did not work for you? the closing of PGAdmin, the process killing or the file move/rename?

Answer (score -1):

I hade the same problem today, i found this Post: [PostgreSQL-Mailinglist](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFOhELdxCg4%2B7YfONyr4seMOuP4UycCkd3H9-CcB23RqpMzW7g%40mail.gmail.com) with the given answer:

> First, click on "Click here for details" link on the dialogue (same
> dialogue you have attached).  When you click on that, another dialogue
> (details of backup) will show up. Please close that another dialogue
> through the close button (at upper right), this window will not show up
> again.

I had to do this ~3 times, and now the "Backup-Window" is gone.